# How to invalidate / refresh a domain instance association?

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, grails, caching, grails-orm

There is a bug in Grails preventing me from using removeFrom* when the node I'm trying to remove is extending the collection type. Removing the node directly from the association won't update the second level cache.

> A hasMany B

Is there any way to manually invalidate or force a reload on an association cache? Invoking refresh() on the many side didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the `SessionFactory` instance, you could use `evictCollection`:

```
sessionFactory.evictCollection("Cat.kittens", catId); //evict a particular collection of kittens
sessionFactory.evictCollection("Cat.kittens"); //evict all kitten collections
```